# ImportError: No module named google_compute_engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, centos6, gsutil

I used google compute engine from Google Cloud Platform , and I want to store my data in googles storage, so I used the gsutil to send data from compute engine to google storage

Before i updated python2.6.6 to  python2.7, gsutil was working fine.
But after update to 2.7

[image]

it took me lots of time...

P.S I use CenOS6.7

Answer (score 35):

I had exactly the same problem, and I solved it by removing boto settings:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/boto.cfg
```

Answer (score 17):

This is related to [this](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7940) issue.

Can be solved by running `export BOTO_CONFIG=/dev/null` before running `gsutil`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

> `vim /etc/boto.cfg`

Find the directive where it says:

```
[Plugin]
plugin_directory = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto
```

And comment out the `plugin_directory` by placing the `#` at the start of the line:

```
[Plugin]
#plugin_directory = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto
```

Or, set the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable in the same command:

`BOTO_CONFIG=/dev/null gsutil <your command here> ...`

Comment: While this might work, it's not a durable solution, because the `/etc/boto.cfg` file contains an explicit warning at the top: "This file is automatically created at boot time [...] Do not edit this file directly"